# Order when item is out of stock

Tags: cartthrob

Maybe I'm overseeing this, but I can't see to work it out.
Customer asks me if it's possible to add items to the cart even if there's no stock.

At the moment an error is generated, saying out of stock.

Any idea if this is somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you are going to be able to do this is by unticking the "Track Stock" checkbox.

When you click the Track Stock button you are telling CartThrob I only have "X" amount of items so it is going to only allow you to sell "X" amount of items.

Comment: Any idea where to find this? Looked everywhere & can't find it. Using 2.5 version of Cartthrob

Answer (score 0):

You would most likely want to check your template for something like the following and remove those lines:

```
{if "{product_inventory}" > 0} 
   ...
{if:else}
  This item is out of stock
{/if}
```

You could also try clearing the "Product Inventory Field Name" field within the "Products" configuration page. This would allow you to have no stock control.

Give the first one or both solutions a try to see if it suits your needs.